# multiple tabs on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the need for multiple tabs on a single page, how can I adjust the code to accommodate this?

Please see the [codepen](http://codepen.io/robbo/pen/Dxewb)

This is my jquery so far:

```
var e = $(".tabContainer ul li a");
    $(".tabContents.active").show();
    e.click(function (t) {
        t.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            var n = $(this).attr("href");
            e.removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".tabContents").hide();
            $(n).fadeIn()
        }
    });
```

I'm guessing put this into a function and call it using a unique id on each tab container?

Please excuse the html and css, this is just a rough copy of the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

in working with css try flexbox,its very handy and is designed for applications like yours.

go through this link.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/